# MySQL LOAD XML with multiple of the same fields

Tags: mysql, xml, load

I'm new to MySQL and am trying to use the LOAD XML to populate a table. The issue is that the XML isn't one that I've created so I have no way of making it so it is the "perfect" format when I'm reading it in.

Here is an example of the XML file:

```
<program id="1">
  <date>20130308</date>
  <category>Business</category>
  <category>Series</category>
</program>
```

I have a table with these columns:

```
program, date, category, category_2
```

This is the MySQL code:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Test/BHTest.xml'
INTO TABLE bh_test
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<program>';
```

If I use the LOAD XML, I get the second category saved in the "category" field and the "category_2" field is null.

So, how do I go about getting both categories to show up in the same row??

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Even I am facing the same problem. Has anyone found any solution to this?